# WPF C# image brightness

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

I loaded an `Image` into `BitmapImage`.

`XAML`

```
<Image Margin="12,12,16,71" Name="imgPhoto">
```

`Code behind`

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Title = "Select a picture";
op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";

if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
}
```

How can I change the brightness of this `Image`?

Comment: Did you use google? Ok, here it is: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/05/23/brightness-and-contrast-manipulation-in-wpf-3-5-sp1.aspx

Comment: Yes,  I used google but I don`t know how to use this HLSL. Is there any other easier option? I tried to get single pixels and increase R,G,B values but it doesn`t work